# How to insert html character encodings into Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, html-entities

I'd really love to be able to insert, for instance, `&#8203;` or `<wbr>` or any other codepoint that will make the documentation more expressive or look nicer.

For instance the word break character is really useful to put between parts of a long file path so that it can break at slashes on mobile devices.

I can't seem to find a syntax that allows anything other than the ones listed at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html

I even tried pasting the (invisible) characters directly into my c++ source code, but Doxygen didn't like that.

Comment: There is no real way to use these type of entities. One could try to fiddle around with the `\htmlonly` / `\htmlonly[block]` command but this would most likely introduce some unwanted extra spaces in the result. It would probably not be a big problem to implement these entities into doxygen in respect to the HTML output but a bigger problem would be the other output formats (LaTeX, RTF, Docbook...).